# Is there a regularly updated resource that lists the most used browser versions?

Tags: internet, browser, users

Is there a resource that is regularly updated that lists the most used browsers versions?
I know resources that list browsers by usage but they don't include the browser version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Net Applications](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0&qptimeframe=M)
- [Clicky](http://www.getclicky.com/marketshare/global/web-browsers/versions/)
- [Wikimedia](http://stats.wikimedia.org/archive/squid_reports/2012-04/SquidReportClients.htm)
- [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201204-201204-bar)

Answer (score 2):

[gs.statcounter.com](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201104-201204)

For seeing when certain features (such as HTML5 support, Css3 support) will be available in a certain browser, [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) is a useful resource.

Answer (score 1):

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) maintains a nice list. They also include version information:

[image]